# Oracle comparison empty string and space bug?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

this select on Oracle 11 work ok

```
select 
*
FROM
ALL_CONSTRAINTS C
WHERE C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE='P'
AND COALESCE(C.INDEX_NAME, ' ')<>' ' /* space */
```

but this return no rows

```
select 
*
FROM
ALL_CONSTRAINTS C
WHERE C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE='P'
AND COALESCE(C.INDEX_NAME, '')<>'' /* empty string */
```

as you can see difference is only between

COALESCE(C.INDEX_NAME, '')<>'' and COALESCE(C.INDEX_NAME, ' ')<>' '

I do not understand why this happened - a bug?
Or i missed something

Comment: Because Oracle considers the empty string to be NULL and NULL is never equal to or unequal to any other value including NULL.

Comment: Thanks you, i am new in Oracle. And yes this post is duplicate of that link. I do not find it, but my assumption was wrong and i search for different words